# Which APIs would be appropriate to display the normal screen in an NSView

Tags: cocoa, opengl, core-graphics, quartz-2d

Which API would be appropriate to display the normal screen in a view? Conceptually, I would like to take the live video that would normally be the full screen, and display that in a view in a kiosk kind of mode? Would that be out of stream and impossible with public APIs?

Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Core Graphics API provides a set of functions enabling a block to be invoked every time a new screen frame is ready:

- [`CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayStreamCreateWithDispatchQueue)
- `CGDisplayStreamStart` / `CGDisplayStreamStop`

You could take the `IOSurface` provided by that API and display it in your own kiosk window.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017895/capture-screen-with-cgdisplaystream) provides some sample code for the `CGDisplayStream` API, and [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/MultiGPUIOSurface/Listings/ServerOpenGLView_m.html) demonstrates how to render an `IOSurface` to an `NSOpenGLView`.

Comment: This sounds right on course. Would this potentially allow creating a virtual display in a view or window? Or am I thinking in black holes?

Comment: I looked at the stream API and it looks geared toward streaming a display's buffer somewhere but trying to do it on the same display would be crazy unless I could create a context that renders out of stream. I would almost need to render every other frame and stream in between frames... Does it make sense?

Comment: What I'm thinking of is how iChat / Messages renders my screen in a tiny window while viewing another persons shared screen.

Comment: @uchuugaka: You could take the image CGDisplayStream gives you (it's basically an OpenGL texture) and render it to a window, or render it full-screen on a different display.

Comment: But if the destination is on the same display, it will be a video feedback loop (infinite tunnel) at best. Unless there is a way to exclude a window or context from being in the stream.

Comment: If you want to exclude certain windows from the capture, you could instead use the CGWindow API.  See [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html).