# Using CGDisplayStream with a Queue

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, grand-central-dispatch

I'm working on implementing screen-capturing of a Mac app suing `CGDisplayStream`, similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017895/capture-screen-with-cgdisplaystream), but in Swift.

Below is the code I have in my app's single ViewController:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {

    super.viewDidAppear()

    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.queue",
                                        qos: .background,
                                        target: nil)


    let displayStream  = CGDisplayStream(dispatchQueueDisplay: 0, outputWidth: 100, outputHeight: 100,pixelFormat: Int32(k32BGRAPixelFormat), properties: nil, queue: backgroundQueue) { (status, code, iosurface, update) in

        switch(status){
        case .frameBlank:
            print("FrameBlank")
            break;
        case .frameIdle:
            print("FrameIdle")
            break;
        case .frameComplete:
            print("FrameComplete")
            break;
        case .stopped:
            print("Stopped")
            break;
        }

        self.update()

    }

    displayStream?.start()

}


func update(){
    print("WORKING")
}
```

What seems to be happening is that the queue process isn't being properly initialized, but I'm not sure...when the app starts, the `self.update()` is called once, but only once. Given that the display stream has started properly, I would expect this function to be called repeatedly, but it's only called once.

Anyone have any ideas? Am I not setting up a queue properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that no reference to `displayStream` is kept outside
of `viewDidAppear`, so the stream will be deallocated on return
of that method.

Making it a property of the view controller should solve the problem:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var displayStream: CGDisplayStream?

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        // ...

        displayStream = CGDisplayStream(...)
        displayStream?.start()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear() {
        super.viewWillDisappear()
        displayStream?.stop()
        displayStream = nil
    }

}
```

Releasing the stream in `viewWillDisappear` breaks the retain cycle
and allows the view controller to be deallocated (if it is part of
a view controller hierarchy).

Comment: Yup, that was exactly the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Another gotcha with similar symptoms that stumped me for a moment: the handler callback only fires when there are changes to the input display. So, if you are like me and do most of your work on an external monitor, the callback may not fire until you move your mouse onto the display that you have selected as the input display.